# frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'. --

Tags: ios, node.js, express, outlook, safari

I created a complement to outlook, but i need to use iframe to load one  page. It is working in web (safari and chrome), windows (web and outlook), but when i have tried to use the complement in outlook mac, it is showing the next error

The code is

```
<!-- Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved. Licensed under the MIT License. -->
<!-- This file shows how to design a first-run page that provides a welcome screen to the user about the features of the add-in. -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <title>Contoso Task Pane Add-in</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/assets/css/docs.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- Office JavaScript API -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/office.js"></script>
        <!-- For more information on Fluent UI, visit https://developer.microsoft.com/fluentui#/. -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://static2.sharepointonline.com/files/fabric/office-ui-fabric-core/11.0.0/css/fabric.min.css" />

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.12.9/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/src/taskpane/taskpane.js"></script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div style="background-color: lavender;">
            <iframe src="https://login.microsoftonline.com" title="workspace" class="iframe" style="height: 800px; width: 100%;"></iframe>
        </div>   
    </body>
</html>
```

Error is

> Refused to display 'https://login.microsoftonline.com' in a frame
> because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'.